# Barcode scan into java swing app intermittently fails on embedded tab control characters

Tags: java, swing, barcode, java-5

I have a java swing application which has a form that I populate by scanning a barcode containing tab (or $I) delimited data as keyboard input through a USB connection. Intermittently, the form's text fields are incorrectly populated such that it appears the tab is processed too late.  For example, if the data set in the barcode is something like 'abc$Idef', the expected output would be 'abc' in the 1st text field and 'def' in the 2nd text field. What we see sometimes instead is 'abcde' in the 1st text field and 'f' in the 2nd or even all data in the 1st text field and nothing in the 2nd.

I have seen this issue manifest at different frequencies across different days. Today could be good and I only see it happen 1 out of every 150 attempts.  Yesterday it could have been poor, happening 1 out of 10 attempts. The scanner is at or near default factory settings with the exception of me toggling the parameter to implement tab vs $I delimiter. I have also attempted slowing down the transmission speed, and while that does appear to decrease the frequency of events, it does not eliminate them and the the slowed speed is not ideal for user workflow and so, reset it to full speed.

I am doubtful that the issue lies within the scanner however. in the application, I've attempted to disable all text field validations and data backups to essentially remove any custom code which might cause some delay, but the intermittent issue still exists. Currently the application is running on a WinXPSP3 using JRE 1.5.0_18. The scanner is a Symbol model ds6707. I could use some guidance in investigating this issue further to determine where the problem may lie.

Comment: This sounds like incorrect synchronization. At a minimum, verify that all Swing GUI objects are constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Further analysis of the issue is looking like focus traversal on the AWT queue is not playing nicely consistently with the EDT such that it is being consumed too late and the next char(s) from the barcode stream are being read prior to moving to the next control.  I am trying to get the tab movement to block the EDT (or be added to it) but so far have had little success.  Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Rereading that, I may have worded that incorrectly. What i am trying to accomplish is having the tab processed prior to the character after it 100% of the time. Since inserts are handled by the control's listener and tabs are handled by the traversal policy, there seems to be a problem remaining completely synchronized. That tab needs to be on the event dispatch thread at the appropriate time. I'm thinking a change to the focus manager or traversal policy  is what's needed but could use a little help getting nailed down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading the stream on a separate thread and posting completed units on the [`EventQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html). This will ensure that events arrive "Sequentially…In the same order as they are enqueued." [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) is convenient for this, as the `process()` method executes "asynchronously on the *Event Dispatch Thread*."

Comment: Ultimately, this is what we needed to do in the short term. Not exactly how we wanted it to work, but for the sake of time it was good enough and will open up discussions for a redesign.  thank you.

Comment: You say `Consider reading the stream on a separate thread`, can you please elaborate a little more on this? By `stream` are you talking about the barcode string? How would someone be supposed to read it on a separate thread?

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel: Yes, perform I/O asynchronously on the worker's background thread; I've added a link above.

Comment: My doubt is about how to read I/O related to the barcode reader. In the question you can see `data as keyboard input through a USB connection`, it seems that the barcode is being used in 'software wedge` mode (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode_reader#Keyboard_wedges) so there is no any explicit stream to read from, barcode reader acts like a person typing on the keyboard with a _constant_ timing

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel: I've read that some drivers put the stream on _standard input_, as if someone were typing, but I've never heard it called a _keyboard wedge_; thanks for the information. I'd use `ProcessBuilder` to read _standard input_. Ping me if you open a question on this topic.